# How long does each of the stages in meiosis take?

Tags: cell-biology, reproduction, meiosis, eukaryotic-cells, cell-division

For each stages of meiosis (i.e. Interphase, Prophase I, ...), I wanted to know the time between each stages either in percentages or minutes. However, while I could find the cell cycle for mitosis like the image [(original link)](https://johnosborneabcbiology.wordpress.com/cell-biology-topic-1/the-origin-of-cells-1-5-cell-division-1-6), I couldn't find such thing for meiosis. Does anybody know anything about this?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the figure directly above the image you posted in [the link you posted](https://johnosborneabcbiology.wordpress.com/cell-biology-topic-1/the-origin-of-cells-1-5-cell-division-1-6), you'll see a very different set of figures.

[image]

It turns out, time spent in different phases of the cell cycle depends on species, cell type, and conditions, specifically, the presence of cell cycle regulating signals like cyclins. You can also read about that in the link you posted.

Meiosis is similarly varied. For example, in a female human, oogonia start meiosis while the female is still a fetus. Meiosis is then arrested in prophase 1. Further progression in meiosis doesn't occur until puberty at the earliest. Spermatogenesis in a human male, on the other hand occurs over a 64 day period. Since oocytes sit in prophase 1 for ~ 13-50 years, they will have a very different proportion of time spent in each phase. You can read about this in Costanza Physiology, chapter 10.